# Does doc2vec model give accuracy on non-dictionary words?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I have sentences in corpus with mixed words (dictionary and non-dictionary words). Non-dictionary words are as important as they are domain specific. I'm not performing any nlp on non-dictionary words. Does doc2vec model compare non-dictionary words to same words in matching criteria?

Ex. I'm giving input ['AMDML','release']. Here AMDML is domain specific word. Will it match to same words if I've sentences in training model like ['AMDML','release','process'] or ['DML','release']. or only words like 'release' and 'process' is matched in most similar method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I guess not;**

According to [radimrehurek-gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html#introducing-paragraph-vector) page which mentioned [Le and Mikolov paper](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Equocle/paragraph_vector.pdf) (introducers of Doc2Vec algorithm), They refer to the Paragraph Vector model as Doc2Vec;

> In Gensim, we refer to the Paragraph Vector model as Doc2Vec. Which usually outperforms such simple-averaging of Word2Vec vectors.
> The basic idea is: act as if a document has another floating word-like
> vector, which contributes to all training predictions, and is updated
> like other word-vectors, but we will call it a doc-vector. Gensim’s
> Doc2Vec class implements this algorithm.

So i guess Doc2Vec just follow Word2Vec model/algorithm; As i know if Word2Vec model for example has **`AMDML`** word on its training corpus it can generate a vector for it; Otherwise it has know idea about that and show something like `error: missing word` to you or at least returns padding/empty vector.

I think you need something like [fasttext](https://fasttext.cc/); fasttext model always has vector for any words even if they don't exist on its traianing corpus; Unlike word2vec, fasttext can learn from n-gram character of words so you can find similar words by measuring their similarity values. After that for each sentence/doc averaging these similarities and find similar sentences/docs.

Comment: Got it. What if my training corpus has AMDML as a word in one sentence. And when I am giving one sentence in input (that includes AMDML, too) for finding most similar sentence from model, will it consider that word in matching criteria? That's actually my question.

Comment: @VishalSolanki ; yes but not directly (i mean it dose not check if that word in that sentence or not it will check it mathematically); ADML has a vector (list of numerical values - depends on number of your neurons) so when some models like doc2vec do simple-averaging of Word2Vec vectors the ADML vector weights will effect on the final similarity ratio between two sentences.

Comment: @VishalSolanki; if i answered your question would you plz accept my answer ?